# Exporting DXF from Revit to QGIS, loss of coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, dxf, revit

I'm trying to combine Revit and QGIS. It's mostly about exporting Revit files as DXF and opening them in QGIS.

Every file, no matter how I try to work with the projection in Revit (survey point and basepoint, and I've tried converting to both UTM, WGS84 etc etc.), ends up in 'Null Island' in QGIS. I cannot fathom how it works, if it 'breaks' when converted to DXF or if it's already in Revit, I'm mucking it up.

I've been looking up information online, but have yet to find anything specifically close to my issue.

Is it possible to export a Revit file to QGIS, with an actual projection?
And if so, where is that information/material available?

Comment: Try these solutions :
[https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384327/error-when-trying-to-import-dwg-file-in-qgis-3-10-9](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384327/error-when-trying-to-import-dwg-file-in-qgis-3-10-9)

Comment: I don't really see how it matches my problem. My issue is not the import of the DXF file but that it doesn't retain the coordinates, when converting a revit file, to DXF and then importing to qgis.

Comment: A DXF has no projection. In the end, there are no coordinates in it, but numbers.
When importing into QGIS, you need to specify which projection the numbers are in.
What coordinate system (CRS) are you working in?
Which coordinates (numbers) are displayed in CAD?
Which country/state?
Can you upload the dxf?

Comment: I'm working in ETRS89/UTM zone 32N - EPSG:25832. In terms of the coordinates in CAD, I'm not sure. The DXF are converted Revit files; not sure if that makes a difference?I'm trying to learn Revit, but I have a hard time figuring out how it works in coordinate systems, and there doesn't really seem to be options either.

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to understand the nature of your problem without having the .dxf file generated by REVIT.
Anyway, have you already tried what suggested by the user Mapperz in the post that I had pointed out to you?

To improve compatibility it is always preferable to save the vector in [.dxf or .dwg format](https://wiki.esko.com/display/KBA/KB73958874%3A+ArtiosCAD+-+How+to+determine+in+which+AutoCAD+version+the+DXF+file+was+created) with a version <= AutoCAD R2014 so that it can be read without problems with QGIS.

If the vector in REVIT is georeferenced to EPSG:25832 you should read coordinate values inside the projected bounds: -1877994.66, 3932281.56 <-> 836715.13, 9440581.95

If you use arbitrary coordinates then you should use the [vector blender](https://github.com/olivierdalang/VectorBender#---vectorbender---) plugin to georeference it in QGIS.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)